# Ajax with primary key in url of Django cannot work

Tags: django, url

all, i am using Django to do a social website and now i am trying to do friend network.
The problem i encountered now is when i am using ajax to pass user id in url and it throw url cannot be found error, maybe see code the will be much clearer.
the code is as following

i tried to take awayid, that is , take away all id in ajax, url, and method, then it can work. but if i add id parameter in, then it cannot work

```
html template

<button class="add-friend-btn" id="add-friend"> Add friend 

<script src="{% static 'account/js/friends.js'%}" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var userprofilePk = "{{userprofile.pk}}"; // other user's id(primary key)
</script>
{% endif %}
```

```
javascript friend.js


$(document).ready(function() {
    var addFriend = document.getElementById('add-friend');

    addFriend.addEventListener("click", function (event) {

         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            headers: { "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken },
            url: "ajax/friend-request/send/"+userprofilePk+"/",
            data: {
                "test": "test",
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {

            },
            error: function (error) {
            },
         });

    });
});
```

```
Django url


urlpatterns = [
    re_path("ajax/friend-request/send/<pk>/", views.send_friend_request, name="user_send_request"),

]
```

```
views.py

def send_friend_request(request, id):
    print("send_friend_request")
    payload = {"test": "test"}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(payload), content_type='application/json')
```

the error message is:

```
Not Found: /account/profile/sm10547/ajax/friend-request/send/2/
app_1    | HTTP POST /account/profile/sm10547/ajax/friend-request/send/2/ 404 [0.01, 172.18.0.1:38852]
```

Comment: Paste the debug log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you are using normal URL dispatcher like **path** use **path
   converters** to capture URL parameters like `<int:pk>` for example: 
   `path("ajax/friend-request/send/<int:pk>/",
   views.send_friend_request, name="user_send_request")`. [docs for path()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#example)
2. If you're using regex URL dispatcher like **re_path** use regular
   expression to catch URL parameters like `(?P<pk>[0-9])` for example: use `re_path(r"ajax/friend-request/send/(?P<pk>[0-9])/$", views.send_friend_request, name="user_send_request")`. [docs for re_path()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#using-regular-expressions)

In your case use `re_path(r"ajax/friend-request/send/(?P<pk>[0-9])/$", views.send_friend_request, name="user_send_request")` it should work fine.

Comment: yes! it works , iforgot need to use regular expression! thank u very much!